# How can I use an existing property as the doc_id using Python CouchDb library Create or Save methods?

Tags: python, twitter, couchdb

Background - I am storing some tweets in CouchDb, and I want to make it easy to prevent storing duplicate tweets by using the Twitter Id as the CouchDb document id.

I am using a Python script to extract some tweets from Twitter using the python-twitter library, which returns a collection of objects, each of which contains the unique Twitter tweet id as a property (twitter.Status.id). I would like to use this as the CouchDb document id when saving the tweet into CouchDb.

```
>>> import twitter
>>> api = twitter.Api()
>>> statuses = api.GetSearch('xyz')
>>> s = statuses[0] # save just the first one for now

>>> import couchdb
>>> couch = couchdb.Server()
>>> dbcouch = couch['tweets']
>>> dbcouch.save(s.AsDict())
(u'fd55e5944267266892f076891a3d9ac4', u'1-4a50a618afd4dc68373155b1ad3e96a1')
```

CouchDb has set a unique Id, which is not what I want. The documentation has examples of setting a manual doc id when the document is being built from scratch, but in this case (where the object is handed to me) I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get an `"_id"` field in the status before saving it to couch. For example (my Python is rusty)

```
>>> s = statuses[0] # save just the first one for now
>>> tweet = s.AsDict()
>>> tweet["_id"] = "%d" % tweet["id"]

>>> # (Couch stuff same as before)
>>> dbcouch.save(tweet)
```

How does that work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jason, but that doesn't work. I'll accept the answer but will edit your code sample if that's OK. (You the dbcouch.save() method chokes if the _id property is an integer, so you need to cast it as a string. ?

Comment: Every time I write Python it becomes more clear how rusty I am. I changed line 3 to use a string. Does that help?